# How to get a nested routeName in the Parents route or controller in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a nested route and I want to do something on that route. To do that I need to determine when I am on that route.

I'd like to do this from the Parents route or controller. I have tried using

```
routeName
fullRouteName
```

in the Parent route but these only return the Parents route name.

Is there a way to get a Child routes name in the Parent route?

Comment: You do not provide enough information for a proper answer. What do you need to do, and where? Why do you need to know which nested route you are on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to dynamically retrieve the child route(s) as you can always look at `router.js` to view all child routes which are always going to be hardcoded, however, you can look into using the [child property on the RouteInfo object](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.10/classes/RouteInfo/properties/child?anchor=child)